# Построить без рекурсии

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, рекурсия

Можно ли вывести такое в виде дерева без использования рекурсии ?

```
[{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15,"children":[{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18}]}]
```

Сейчас это выглядит так, но что-то подсказывает, что можно проще

```
function buildItem(item){

    var html = "<li class='dd-item' data-id='"+item.id+"'>";
    html += "<div class='dd-handle'>item "+item.id+"</div>";

    if( item.children ) {

        html += "<ol class='dd-list'>";
        for (var i = 0; i < item.children.length; i++)
        {
            html += buildItem(item.children[i]);
        };
        html += "</ol>";

    }

    html += "</li>";
    return html;
}

var data = JSON.parse(item);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    content += buildItem(data[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой рекурсивный код можно переписать без использования рекурсии. Только получится намного сложнее и непонятнее:

```js
function startItem(item) {
  return "<li class='dd-item' data-id='" + item.id + "'>" +
    "<div class='dd-handle'>item " + item.id + "</div>";
}

function endItem() {
  return "</li>";
}

function startList() {
  return "<ol class='dd-list'>";
}

function endList() {
  return "</ol>";
}

function buildItem(item) {
  var openedItems = [
    [item, -1]
  ];
  var content = '';
  while (openedItems.length) {
    var current = openedItems.pop();
    var currentItem = current[0];
    var childIndex = current[1];
    if (childIndex == -1) {
      content += startItem(currentItem);
    }
    ++childIndex;
    var children = currentItem.children || [];
    if (childIndex >= children.length) {
      if (children.length)
        content += endList(currentItem);
      content += endItem(currentItem);
    } else {
      if (!childIndex)
        content += startList(currentItem);
      openedItems.push([currentItem, childIndex]);
      openedItems.push([currentItem.children[childIndex], -1]);
    }
  }
  return content;
}

var json = '[{"id":13,"children":[{"id":33},{"id":34}]},{"id":14},{"id":15,"children":[{"id":16},{"id":17, "children": [{"id": 38}, {"id": 39}]},{"id":18}]}]';
var data = JSON.parse(json);
var content = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  content += buildItem(data[i]);
};
document.body.innerHTML = content;
```

Ваша задача рекурсивная по своей природе, поэтому рекурсию тут использовать вполне естественно. Проблема с переполнением стека вам скорее всего не грозит, если вы конечно не собираетесь строить списки с уровнем вложенности ~10000.

Comment: Да, действительно выглядит более запутанно. Но все равно спасибо огромное за проделанную работу.